# Apache or php.ini configuration to allow save files using phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have been looking for information, examples, documentation... but my search failed, because i did not find any solution to my problem: i use XAMPP to design a webpage over php and mysql, prior to upload the final version to my server (this is in order to perform functionality tests). I implemented the phpspreadsheet in XAMPP to generate xlsx, it works fine, and creates the correspondent excel file in the local drive location specified. But..... when i upload the files to my server, all works fine except the generation of xlsx, i mean: the excel file is not saved to the server. Both server and xampp have the same versions of php, mysql, phpspreadsheet, i already change the permission of folder to 777 in order to give complete access to script to save the expected file generated, however no file is generated or saved to location specified in php script. I have tried by using a very simple test php file and neither it saves the excel file, no errors are showed and aparently all instructions are executed correctly (the xlsx is only not generated in server, in windows by using xampp works perfectly), i really dont know if there is a special configuration that i miss to do, in order to allow php in apache save files. Thank you for your help.

Test 1: works fine only in xampp, in server it did not generates errors but is not saving the file in any place.

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('template.xlsx');
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Test text ok!!!');

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");

$writer->save("test.xlsx");

?>
```

Test 2: works fine on server and xampp but generate excel to internet explorer output window instead save it to a location, it is ok, but not what i need, i need store (save) the file in server.

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('template.xlsx');
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Test text ok!!!');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xlsx" ');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
$writer->save('php://output');
?>
```

Accordong to the examples shown above, i can state that: paths refered to Phpspreadsheet for \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet... and related to directives and instructions are working fine for both environments (xampp and lamp-server) because the second example works, however in the first example the only thing that does not work is the save() function. This is the reason why i think that problem is not related to Phpspreadsheet configuration and/or php file coding, but apache or php permission for saving files. Anyone have some ideas why the script is not saving anything in my server? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, So show us the code or a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Currently from what you tell us, we can only make guesses. Thats not productive for you or us, so many wont even bother reading all your question

Comment: ___My first guess___ _Yes I am going to make a guess_ You are using a windows bases path to save the file to. Remember Unix does not know what for example  `C:\xxx` is, Unix does not use drives in that way.

Comment: @RiggsFolly hi again, i wrote in the comments/answer the example that i am using for this particular case. I hope someone can help with this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help, after looking desperately over web, forums, chats, finally i found solution: i just apply the command  "chcon -R -t httpd_system_rw_content_t mydirectory" to specify that path has content readable writeable over apache by owner.